# Running curl command from Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, curl, jira, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to execute the curl post command from Jenkins declarative pipeline, however, it is throwing a syntax error -- **Expecting '}' found ':'**

The pipeline script is below:

```
pipeline {

   agent { label ' Linux01'}

   stages {

      stage('Hello') {

         steps {

            sh 'curl -u username:password -X POST -d '{"body":"Jenkinspipleinecomment"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/someissue/comment'
    
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out

```yaml
pipeline {

agent { label ' Linux01'}

stages {

  stage('Hello') {

     steps {

        sh """curl -u username:password -X POST -d '{"body":"Jenkinspipleinecomment"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/someissue/comment"""

     }
  }
} }
```

Comment: Glad that it help. :)